# how can the probabilities of sampling subset proportions be tested?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, z-statistic

Assume we have 10 different jigsaw puzzles. Each puzzle has a different number of pieces, e.g.,

```
1st puzzle = 100 pieces
2nd puzzle = 120 pieces
3rd puzzle = 240 pieces
.
.
.
```

Further, assume we take all the pieces from all the different puzzles and put them together in one pile (n = 100 + 120 + 240 + ...). Now, assuming we take a sample of X pieces from the pile and find that we have picked a certain number of pieces from each puzzle such that:

```
X = 100
3/100 cover 1st puzzle 3/100
23/100 cover 2nd puzzle 23/120
12/100 cover 3rd puzzle 12/240
```

I am interested in calculating the probability of getting a certain coverage (or proportion) of each puzzle (separately) from sample X. I am not interested in the probability of the proportion distribution (as can be found using chi squared goodness of fit).

Essentially, I would like to show that a very high coverage of a small puzzle has a very low probability in a small sample.

My questions are:

1. Assuming the sampling is random is it valid to use a one-tailed z-statistic to find the p-value.
2. Assuming the sampling is initially random, but from sample X only those pieces that answer a certain criteria (e.g., colour or wight) are considered in the puzzle coverage calculation, is the z-statistic test still valid?
3. Finally, what test would be appropriate if some pieces fit more than one puzzle?

(Just to clarify, this is not homework!)

Comment: Looks like you want a multinomial distribution.

Comment: thanks for the comment. so you would suggest a chi square goodness of fit to calculate p-value for the entire distribution and not to calculate a separate one for each proportion? I trying to eliminate the unprovable ones.

Comment: I'd sum the multinomials for the cases you are thinking of. But there may be better methods.

Comment: could you please elaborate? maybe an answer :)

Comment: @PeterFlom The sampling situation described sounds like [multivariate hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution) to me, not multinomial, since the pieces are sampled *without replacement*, in exactly the way that the hypergeometric relates to the binomial when sampling without replacement. Picking the wrong one can make a substantial difference in this kind of problem, since the closer you get to getting all the pieces in one puzzle, the harder the last few pieces are to get.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. I'll delete my answer, below.

Comment: Thanks @glen-b. do you think that multivariate hypergeometric could be also used in the case of pieces fitting more than in puzzle?

Comment: @Glen_b would Wallenius’ noncentral hypergeo-metric distribution be appropriate? do you know of a R package for that?

Comment: I didn't see that first comment until just now (you didn't quite get the username right so it didn't alert me). No, the multivariate hypergeometric doesn't fit that circumstance. I don't know the answer to your second set of questions from a few minutes ago, sorry.